# How to set Formik form errors from redux store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk, formik

I am working on pretty standard React/Redux/Redux-thunk style app.

I have a Login form of Formik. Inside onSubmit I have action call userLogin(). thunk take care of API call and if there is an error, thunk dispatch LOGIN_USER_ERROR action which update store with this error.

So inside my Login component I have mapped error prop from store saying for example wrong email or password error.

currently i'm managing inside catch of dispatch userLogin but i want through redux store.

My question is pretty simple: How to update Formik form after error prop is updated? Same question goes for un-general server errrors like {'username': 'Already exists'}. I need to show error feedback under input like when I was validating on client side before call.

now i have to manage sync way of programming.

[image: dispatch user login from login component]

Comment: resolved with proper use of redux